# Can you use Hibernate and eBean in the same project?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, ebean

I have a legacy app that has hundreds of Hibernate 5.1 Criteria queries.  Moving to Hibernate 5.2+, these all have to be rewritten using the JPA CriteriaQuery (deprecation warnings in 5.2, I think removed in 5.3).  I use EBean in another app and would like to convert this legacy app to it, but I'd rather do it one screen at a time than rewrite the database layer of the entire application at once.

Comment: Generally screens tend to talk to a more centralised service layer on the back end with shared code and it is that service layer which does the talking to the database. This is different in the design of this application, you really have isolated JPA logic per available page?